# What is the default value for an "other message type" in protobuf 2

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to have a proto response with other message types as fields. I was hoping to only some of these fields and I was wondering what the default value will be if I don't set one of these fields.

The context is the "other message type" listed in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#other

```
message SearchResponse {
  optional Result1 result1 = 1;
  optional Result1 result2 = 2;
}

message Result1 {
  required string url = 1;
  optional string title = 2;
  repeated string snippets = 3;
}

message Result2 {
  required string url2 = 1;
  optional string title2 = 2;
  repeated string snippets2 = 3;
}
```

For example, If I set result1 and not result2, would result2 by null or missing entirely or would result2 be present with the default values for all the strings?

Answer (score 0):

Typically missing, in both proto2 and proto3 - bit it can depend a bit on whether your target platform has a concept of missing.

Consider: messages can be recursive. A `Foo` can have a `Foo` as a field. If it wasn't treated as missing, it would instantly explode.

Comment: Thanks for response. The target platform is Java. Would it be null?

Comment: @JBLevs that would be my expectation, but: try it!